# Key-Value Coding with custom getter, setter and ivar

Tags: objective-c, kvc

I'm wondering how Key-Value Coding, to access a property value, works in Objective-C when this property has a custom getter, setter and ivar defined. According to [Accessor Search Patterns](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/SearchImplementation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000955) the runtime will first search for a getter method and fall back to finding an ivar using the reflection string.

According to the search pattern, when neither a getter nor an ivar are found, an exception should be thrown.

However, when I run the following code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Class1 : NSObject {
    NSInteger prop;
}

@property (getter=customGetter,setter=customSetter:) NSInteger prop;

@end

@implementation Class1
@synthesize prop = customIvar;

@end

int main() {
    Class1 *class1;

    // Create and give the properties some values with KVC...
    class1 = [[Class1 alloc] init];

    class1.prop = 9;
    NSLog(@"Set value to 9 with direct access");

    // Directly access value, should return 9.
    NSLog(@"Direct access: %ld", class1.prop);

    // Set with setValue:forKey: to 20.
    NSLog(@"Set value to 20 with KVC");

    [class1 setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:20] forKey:@"prop"];

    // Directly access value.
    NSLog(@"Direct access: %ld", class1.prop);

    // Access value using KVC
    NSNumber *propVal = [class1 valueForKey:@"prop"];

    NSLog(@"ValueForKey access: %d", [propVal intValue]);
}
```

I get this output:

```
Set value to 9 with direct access
Direct access: 9
Set value to 20 with KVC
Direct access: 9
ValueForKey access: 20
```

It seems that I get two different values: values that are set by directly accessing the property are retrieved when reading directly from the property (`9`). Values that are set using Key-Value Coding are retrieved by using Key-Value Coding (`20`).

Does anyone know how this works internally? Is this behaviour expected and am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following method to your `Class1`:

```
- (void) showVars
{
   NSLog(@"->prop %ld | ->customIVar %ld", prop1, customIvar);
}
```

and call it after you alter your property and you will see what is going on.

Read the reference you linked to, what does it say about the search for a getter and setter?

You've found your answer.

Is it well documented? Probably not, Objective-C & Cocoa have no formal semantic description :-(

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see that the value of the ivar is different than the value of the property. I have read the reference thoroughly and don't see what you mean. Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: The description of the KVC search algorithm specifies exactly what method and var names it searches for; and those do not include any custom getter, settor, or var names...